# MongoDb and ionic2 Get Spesific Data

Tags: mongodb, ionic-framework, ionic2

How can i use find() query in client. I want to see the students whos school name a.

Client side this is my todos.ts provider page.

```
getTodos(){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Authorization', this.authService.token);

      this.http.get('https://myapp.com/api/todos', {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          resolve(data);
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
    }
```

home.ts

```
ionViewDidLoad(){

    this.todoService.getTodos().then((data) => {
          this.todos = data;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log("not allowed");
    });

  }
```

Server side todos.js

```
  exports.getTodos = function(req, res, next){

        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {

            if (err){
                res.send(err);
            }

            res.json(todos);

        });

    }
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: What I must do to get spesific data from MongoDb  ? . I use Find() query  but it's not working.

Comment: You should add all the relevant details here and code..

Comment: Ok, i edit this now